# Fill combobox with a matrix

Tags: c#

I want fill a combobox with a matrix

**Matrix:**

```
object[,] codes = new object[,] { 
            { "1", "BANK S/A" }, 
            { "2", "BANK Center" }, 
            { "3", "BANK AMAZON S/A" }};
```

**Fill my combobox:**

```
comboBank.DataSource = codes;
comboBanco.DataBind();
```

but in my combobox appears the items

```
1
BANK S/A
2
Bank Center
3
Bank Amazon S/A
```

I want fill this combobox with just the names, not the ID's, and in the Value propertie of these combobox, I want the ID.

**What I Want in my combobox**

```
Bank S/A
Bank Center
Bank Amazon S/A
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple helper method you can use to get one column out of a two dimensional array:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetColumn<T>(T[,] array, int column)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        yield return array[i, column];
}
```

Using that you can just modify your code to:

```
comboBank.DataSource = codes.GetColumn(1);
```

Having said that, the real issue here is that you're using a multi-dimensional array when what you really should have is a single dimensional array of some object that contains both an int and a string.

```
public class Code
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
Code[] codes = new Code[]{
    new Code(){ID=1, Name="BANK S/A"},
    new Code(){ID=2, Name="BANK Center"},
    new Code(){ID=3, Name="BANK AMAZON S/A"},
};
```

Once you have that strongly typed array you can either use `Select` to select the property to show, or set the `DisplayMember` of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

for(int i = 0; i < codes.Lenght; i++) 
   list.Add(new { Value = code[i][0], Text = code[i][1] });

comboBox.DataSource = list;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: He has a multidimensional array, not a jagged array.